# Pivot, group or aggregate data frame

Tags: r, aggregate, frequency

Have tried to transform a data table but can't find a way to do it.

I have a data frame like:

```
id letter
 1    a
 2    b
 3    c
 4    c
 5    a
 6    c
```

I would like to transform it to:

```
id    letter frequency(id)
 1,5     a     2
 2       b     1
 3,4,6   c     3
```

I've looked at `cast()` and `table()` and `aggregate()` but not figured it out.

I don't need it as one data frame to start so if there are two different ways to get:

```
 id    letter
 1,5     a
 2       b
 3,4,6   c
```

&

```
letter frequency(id)
 a     2
 b     1
 c     3
```

That's okay. I can combine them. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the `data.table` version,

```
setDT(df)[, .(id = paste(id, collapse = ',')), letter]
#   letter    id
#1:      a   1,5
#2:      b     2
#3:      c 3,4,6

setDT(df)[, .(freq = .N), letter]
#   letter freq
#1:      a    2
#2:      b    1
#3:      c    3
```

Or 2 in 1

```
setDT(df)[, .(id = paste(id, collapse = ','), freq = .N), letter]
#   letter    id freq
#1:      a   1,5    2
#2:      b     2    1
#3:      c 3,4,6    3
```

Comment: Yes, I tried putting unique() outside paste and it didnt work, tried inside paste around id and R crashed.

Comment: just use `setDT(df)[, .(id = paste(unique(id), collapse = ','), freq = .N), letter]`

Comment: It crashed R before, but yeah that works. Possibly crashed because I was trying to update the view() in Rstudio. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One approach to this type of problem is to use `dplyr` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(text = 'id letter
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    c
5    a
6    c', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
df %>% group_by(letter) %>% summarise(freq = n(), idlist = paste(id, collapse = ','))
```

Output is as follows (although you can rearrange the columns if you desire):

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

  letter  freq idlist
   <chr> <int>  <chr>
1      a     2    1,5
2      b     1      2
3      c     3  3,4,6
```

Comment: It is: `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: You may want to get the dev version from github though since that has a few bug fixes. There are many posts on installing packages and also many tutorials on these types of packages.

Comment: You can modify the `paste(id, collapse = ',')` above to `paste(unique(id), collapse = ',')`, which will only create a list of unique id values for each given letter.